# Redis with Redisson framework unpredictable behavior in scala

Tags: scala, concurrency, redis, redisson

I use Redis and Redisson framework with Scala and in it, there are distributed Set and Publish \ Subscribe commands where implemented. When the Set accessed after the system received a message then whole behavior of the frameworks becomes unpredictable. Here are the exception and source code that creates it. Any ideas?

```
import org.redisson.RedissonClient
import org.redisson._

import org.redisson.core.{ RTopic, MessageListener }
import org.scalatest._ 
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
object RedissonTest {


   val config = new Config().setUseLinuxNativeEpoll( true )
   config.useSingleServer().setAddress("127.0.0.1:6379") 

   val redis = Redisson.create( config  )
   val set_test = java.util.UUID.randomUUID
   val system_topic = "system_bus"

   class RedissonTestSet extends FlatSpec with Matchers {

   val topic:RTopic[String] = redis.getTopic( system_topic )
   val redisSet:java.util.Set[String] =  redis.getSet( set_test.toString )

   it should "produce fucking exeption " in {

   val listener = new MessageListener[ String ] () {
    override def onMessage( chanel: String, message: String ) {
      checkSet
    }
  }
  topic.addListener( listener )


  for ( i <- 1 to 1000 ) {
    redisSet.add( i.toString  )
  }
  topic.publish( new String( "hey this is the bug" ) )

}

def checkSet {
  for ( i <-1 to 1000 ) {
    if ( redisSet.contains( i.toString ) ) {
    }
  }
}
}
}
```

The exception:

```
io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: io.netty.util.concurrent.BlockingOperationException: DefaultPromise@447696da(incomplete)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ReplayingDecoder.callDecode(ReplayingDecoder.java:431) ~[netty-codec-4.0.34.Final.jar:4.0.34.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:244) ~[netty-codec-4.0.34.Final.jar:4.0.34.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:307) [netty-transport-4.0.34.Final.jar:4.0.34.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:293) [netty-transport-4.0.34.Final.jar:4.0.34.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelRead(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:86) [netty-transport-4.0.34.Final.jar:4.0.34.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:307) [netty-transport-4.0.34.Final.jar:4.0.34.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:293) [netty-transport-4.0.34.Final.jar:4.0.34.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelRead(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:86) [netty-transport-4.0.34.Final.jar:4.0.34.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:307) [netty-transport-4.0.34.Final.jar:4.0.34.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:293) [netty-transport-4.0.34.Final.jar:4.0.34.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:840) [netty-transport-4.0.34.Final.jar:4.0.34.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe.epollInReady(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:830) [netty-transport-native-epoll-4.0.34.Final-linux-x86_64.jar:na]
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:348) [netty-transport-native-epoll-4.0.34.Final-linux-x86_64.jar:na]
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:264) [netty-transport-native-epoll-4.0.34.Final-linux-x86_64.jar:na]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:112) [netty-common-4.0.34.Final.jar:4.0.34.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:137) [netty-common-4.0.34.Final.jar:4.0.34.Final]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_77]
Caused by: io.netty.util.concurrent.BlockingOperationException: DefaultPromise@447696da(incomplete)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.checkDeadLock(DefaultPromise.java:391) ~[netty-common-4.0.34.Final.jar:4.0.34.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.awaitUninterruptibly(DefaultPromise.java:284) ~[netty-common-4.0.34.Final.jar:4.0.34.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.awaitUninterruptibly(DefaultPromise.java:33) ~[netty-common-4.0.34.Final.jar:4.0.34.Final]
        at org.redisson.command.CommandAsyncService.get(CommandAsyncService.java:84) ~[redisson-2.2.9.jar:na]
        at org.redisson.RedissonObject.get(RedissonObject.java:49) ~[redisson-2.2.9.jar:na]
        at org.redisson.RedissonSet.contains(RedissonSet.java:70) ~[redisson-2.2.9.jar:na]
        at com.web3.RedissonTest$RedissonTestSet$$anonfun$checkSet$1.apply$mcVI$sp(ReddisonSetPubSubTest.scala:45) ~[test-classes/:na]
        at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala:141) ~[scala-library-2.10.4.jar:na]
        at com.web3.RedissonTest$RedissonTestSet.checkSet(ReddisonSetPubSubTest.scala:44) ~[test-classes/:na]
        at com.web3.RedissonTest$RedissonTestSet$$anonfun$1$$anon$1.onMessage(ReddisonSetPubSubTest.scala:30) ~[test-classes/:na]
        at com.web3.RedissonTest$RedissonTestSet$$anonfun$1$$anon$1.onMessage(ReddisonSetPubSubTest.scala:27) ~[test-classes/:na]
        at org.redisson.PubSubMessageListener.onMessage(PubSubMessageListener.java:73) ~[redisson-2.2.9.jar:na]
        at org.redisson.client.RedisPubSubConnection.onMessage(RedisPubSubConnection.java:68) ~[redisson-2.2.9.jar:na]
        at org.redisson.client.handler.CommandDecoder.handleMultiResult(CommandDecoder.java:277) ~[redisson-2.2.9.jar:na]
        at org.redisson.client.handler.CommandDecoder.decodeMulti(CommandDecoder.java:242) ~[redisson-2.2.9.jar:na]
        at org.redisson.client.handler.CommandDecoder.decode(CommandDecoder.java:217) ~[redisson-2.2.9.jar:na]
        at org.redisson.client.handler.CommandDecoder.decode(CommandDecoder.java:97) ~[redisson-2.2.9.jar:na]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ReplayingDecoder.callDecode(ReplayingDecoder.java:376) ~[netty-codec-4.0.34.Final.jar:4.0.34.Final]
        ... 16 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This bug fixed in Redisson 2.2.11